# How to execute maven plugin in a certain phase and with certain configurations through command line?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have made a maven plugin, and I want to execute the plugin by command line without changing anything (e.g., pom.xml) in the benchmark project. Currently, I am using `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal test` (I want to execute my plugin along with the test). But Here are the problems:

1. I do not know how to configure my plugin by command line. For example, if the change to the pom is permitted, there are lots of user-define configurations to set in `<configuration>`, like:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>...</groupId>
       <artifactId>...</artifactId>
       <version>...</version>
       <configuration>
           <debug>true</debug>
           <packageNamePrefix>com/foo/bar</packageNamePrefix>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>...</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   How to use the command line to config those attributes in `<configuration>`?
2. I want to launch my plugin in certain phase (specifically in `LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES`). For example, My mojo class is implemented like:

   ```java
   @Mojo(name = "goal", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST, threadSafe = true)
   @Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES)
   public class myMojo extends MyAbstractMojo {
       ...
   }
   ```

   When I use `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal test` or `mvn test groupId:artifactId:version:goal`, I sadly found that my plugin was launched in incorrect phase. How to fix that? Is there a way to explicitly declare the desire phase in these command lines?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

You can read properties in your plugin and you can set properties on the command line with `-Dproperty=value`.

For the second question:

If you invoke a plugin on the command line directly (as `groupId:artifactId:version:goal`), it does not belong to *any* phase. So if you run

`mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal test`

first the plugin is run, and then all phases from the beginning up to `test`, and if you run

`mvn test groupId:artifactId:version:goal`

then first all phases up to `test` are run, and then your plugin is run.

You cannot specify phases for plugins on the command line.

Comment: Is there a way to execute my plugin goal in the phase `PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES`? I think `PROCESS_TEST_CLASSES` is an intermediate phase of `test`.

Comment: Yes, but only by adding your plugin to the POM.

Comment: If you want to run your plugin between other plugins that run when you call `mvn test`, then you probably have to call **all** the plugins explicitly, i.e. `mvn firstpluging yourplugin secondplugin` instead of using `test`.